# Path to screenshots in Android

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-capture

Is there a way to find out the path used by android to save screenshots?

Can I get the path from a code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android's API has no fixed path for screenshots but

```
File pix = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File screenshots = new File(pix, "Screenshots");
```

might work. That's what ICS uses as path.

Comment: Yes,but it is only for ICS. "/sdcard/ScreenCapture" is a path for screenshots in old samsung devices. "Camera shots" is the path for htc.

Comment: The only thing you can do then is to create a list of paths for each device and match them with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Comment: It was first, what i thought about. But i'll hope find better solution.

Comment: "Phone\Pictures\Screenshots" on my Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: @Delcasda I don't have an S3 to test but `Phone\Pictures` could be what `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` points to on the S3.

Comment: `/Pictures/Screenshots/` on Nexus4 running 4.4 (Kitkat)

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/ on Nexus5 4.4.3

Comment: /storage/emulated/legacy/Pictures/Screenshots on my Nexus 7 with 4.4.3

Comment: On Samsung S6 Edge the 'Screenshots' directory is in DCIM folder not in Pictures ...

Comment: how they differ ? Is they differ by Android API versions ?. Is there any way to get current phone screenshot directory ?

Comment: @zapl Do you have the list of path for each version of android ? Is this differ from Phones or Android API ? Can you  help to find the solution ?

Answer (score 7):

The "Screenshots" value is part of the private API.

[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/screenshot/GlobalScreenshot.java#L97) is link to the source code where the value is set. Since the class is loaded in our application context there is no option to access the field. I'd hardcode it as @zapi suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Few might find this usefull..

```
 public static File mDir= new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)));
 public static File mDirScreenshots = new File(mDir,"Screenshots");
```

And to fetch the screenshots

```
 public static ArrayList<File> getAllScreenshots(File dir){
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            Log.e(YOUR_TAG, "getAllScreenshots: " + i + listFile[i].getName());
            mScreenshotsFiles.add(listFile[i]);
        }
    }
    return mScreenshotsFiles;
}
```