# How do I access the most recent screenshot taken? (Android Studio, Java)

Tags: android, file, screenshot

My goal is to use this in a service class and use an optical character recognizer (Google's API specifically) to read text off of the image and then text-to-speech said text.

My original goal was to programmatically screenshot the device screen, although this seems to be a very involved process since I'm not just taking a screenshot of the views of my application-I'm taking screenshots of the device screen while other apps are open.  I figured manually taking screenshots and then using them this way would allow me to get some functionality out for this sprint in time.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Henry How do I access the most recent screenshot taken? Preferably into a Bitmap object.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667297/path-to-screenshots-in-android