# Access Screenshots directory path for different devices programmtically

Tags: android, screenshot, fileobserver

I have requirement that whenever use capture screenshot from any external or internal app then user should notify that screenshot has been captured. For that i came to know that i can use *FileObserver*.

Okay, So i can do that. But my questions are:

> 1. How to access **Screenshots** folder for different devices?

Because some devices contain in *DCIM* folder and some devices with *Pictures* folder and for other devices actually i don't know.

> 2. Do I need to use **FileObserver** in activity class or should i use background service and put *FileObserver* in that service class?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Path to screenshots in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667297/path-to-screenshots-in-android)

Comment: "I have requirement that whenever use capture screenshot from any external or internal app then user should notify that screenshot has been captured." -- I do not know what an "external... app" is. However, your app has no reliable way to find out about screenshots. "For that i came to know that i can use FileObserver" -- your approach will not work on Android 10+. It also assumes that the screenshot is stored somewhere on the filesystem that your app can access, and there is no guarantee of that. For example, the screenshot might be sent directly to a Web server.